# HTML - Text is not inside the button

Tags: html, css

I'm new here. I just wanted to ask about this problem.

[The text is not inside the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du4Fl.jpg) The text seems to be outside of the box and it looks weird. How do I make the text appear inside the box?  What did I do wrong in the coding? I don't see any problem in my coding. By the way, I use Dreamweaver to code this interface.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Deane.co</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav1">
 <h4><a href="index.html"><h1>Deane.co</a></h4>
 <ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html"</a>Home</li>
    <li><a href="service.html"</a>Products</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"</a>Contact</li>
    <li><a href="about.html"About</a>About</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="main-content">
 <br>
 <h1> Welcome To Deane.co </h1>
 <br>
 <p> Welcome to Deane.co the place to shop beautiful clothes easier </p>
 <br>
 <div id = "products">
 <h5><a href="products.html">Check our products</a></h5>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic"> 
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
 <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
 <p> RM40 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
 <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
 <p> RM40 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
 <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
 <p> RM40 </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 <h2>&copy; Allright Reserved</h2>
 <div>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div> 
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
*{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#nav1 {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
background: #a5aab1;
}
#nav1 h1 {
float: left;
font-size: 2.5em;
margin-left: 15px;

}
#nav1 h1 a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
#nav1 ul {
float: right;
margin-right: 15px;

}
#nav1 ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav1 ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding: 25px;
}
#nav1 ul li:hover{
background: #bfc5ce;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.45s;

}
#active {
background: #bfc5ce;

}

#main-content {
width: 100&;
height: 600px;
background: url(Images/store-background3.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
color: black;
line-height: 40px;

}
#main-content a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
#products {
background: #a5aab1;
width: 170px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: 100;
}
#products:hover {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 10px rgba(136, 131, 131, 0.83);
transition: all ease-in-out 0.45s;
}
#products a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 25px;

}

#shirtsaesthetic {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background: white;
}
#shirtsaesthetic1 {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 19px;
text-align: center;
}
#shirtsaesthetic1 img {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your first bits of code are messed up.
Close tags properly:

```
<head>
<title>Deane.co</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>    
<body>
<div id="nav1">
<h4><a href="index.html"><h1>Deane.co</h1></a></h4>
 <ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="service.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"About>About</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="main-content">
 <br>
 <h1> Welcome To Deane.co </h1>
 <br>
 <p> Welcome to Deane.co the place to shop beautiful clothes easier </p>
 <br>
 <div id = "products">
 <h5><a href="products.html">Check our products</a></h5>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic"> 
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
 <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
 <p> RM40 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
 <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
 <p> RM40 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
 <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
 <p> RM40 </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 <h2>&copy; Allright Reserved</h2>
 <div>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div> 
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css file, remove the line below:

```
 #products a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px; //remove this line
 }
```

In your html file, you missed ">" of a tag in these line:

```
<ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
    <li><a href="service.html"></a>Products</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"> </a>Contact</li>
    <li><a href="about.html"></a>About</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tags in your navigation are wrong, and you need to remove the `padding` from `#products a`

```css
body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
*{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#nav1 {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
background: #a5aab1;
}
#nav1 h1 {
float: left;
font-size: 2.5em;
margin-left: 15px;

}
#nav1 h1 a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
#nav1 ul {
float: right;
margin-right: 15px;

}
#nav1 ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav1 ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding: 25px;
}
#nav1 ul li:hover{
background: #bfc5ce;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.45s;

}
#active {
background: #bfc5ce;

}

#main-content {
width: 100&;
height: 600px;
background: url(Images/store-background3.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
color: black;
line-height: 40px;

}
#main-content a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
#products {
background: #a5aab1;
width: 170px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: 100;
}
#products:hover {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 10px rgba(136, 131, 131, 0.83);
transition: all ease-in-out 0.45s;
}
#products a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;

}

#shirtsaesthetic {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background: white;
}
#shirtsaesthetic1 {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 19px;
text-align: center;
}
#shirtsaesthetic1 img {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Deane.co</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav1">
    <h4><a href="index.html"><h1>Deane.co</a></h4>
    <ul>
      <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="service.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main-content">
    <br>
    <h1> Welcome To Deane.co </h1>
    <br>
    <p> Welcome to Deane.co the place to shop beautiful clothes easier </p>
    <br>
    <div id="products">
      <h5><a href="products.html">Check our products</a></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="shirtsaesthetic">
    <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
      <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
      <p> RM40 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
      <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
      <p> RM40 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
      <h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
      <p> RM40 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <h2>&copy; Allright Reserved</h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  tags in the first unordered list are not closed properly.